# Take xml out from another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have 2 projects (ex Project A and Project B) in one solution.

Project B - `default.aspx` page has below code in load function, which is returning xml.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    string xmlData;

    xmlData = BuildXmlData();
    Response.Write(xmlData);
}
```

Now, I have button on Project A - `default.aspx` page. I want to get that xml data (from Project B `default.aspx` page load function) on button click of Project A `default.aspx` page. I hope you understand the scenario. Please advise how can we do that?

PS : I have tried `server.execute` but its returning raw html.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it server side:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.projectB.com");
        request.Proxy = null;       

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

On clientside javascript you will have to go for an ajax call

Comment: Can we use virtual path instead of site url? Because both application are hosted in IIS and have same solution.

Comment: No, because you want to get the information from projectB which is running on another process. If you want to do that, you should have one web application. But then getting the xml via HTTP would be pointless because you could read the xml from disk.

Comment: So if you want to have to seperated web apps on different location you need to handle it as a http request. If both webapps always run on the same server, consider sharing the xml file and read it from disk

Comment: both application are on same server but xml is being created programatically by calling method on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe you should take a look at webservices or web api's. Call the webservice or api to generate xmls, use the website to show the xml.